# Cannot call the render method

Tags: java, render

My Main class (Named "Component) has the `public static void main(String args[]) {`, and I use it to open the main menu.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        Component component = new Component();

        new Menu(component);
    }
```

This causes the main menu screen to appear as soon as you run the game.
In the main menu once you press a button it will launch the game using `component.start();`

The problem is that I cant can't call the render method in the Menu class since it is the first thing that opens when you run the program

Sorry if its confusing. let me know if you need any additional info. Thanks

The Component class:

```
    public class Component extends Applet implements Runnable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static int pixelSize = 2;

    public static int moveFromBorder = 0;
    public static double sX = moveFromBorder, sY = moveFromBorder; //Side scrolling cords.
    public static double dir = 0;

    public static int width = 700;
    public static int height = 560;

    public int timer = 0;
    public byte movingTimer = 0;

//   Almost full screen is 1350, 732
//       goodish full screen, doesnt encompass the explorer bar is 1350, 690
//       Regular screen 700, 560
    public static Dimension realSize;
    public static Dimension size = new Dimension(700, 560);
    public static Dimension pixel = new Dimension(size.width / pixelSize, size.height / pixelSize);

    public static Point mse = new Point(0, 0); //Mouse.

    public static String name = "MegaTale Alpha 0.0.1";
    public static String version = "0.0.1 Alpha";
    public static String deathText = "You died!";

    public static boolean isRunning = false;
    public static boolean isMoving = false;
    public static boolean isJumping = false;    
    public static boolean isMouseLeft = false;
    public static boolean isMouseRight = false;
    public static boolean hasDragged = false;
    public static boolean isDebug = false;
    public static boolean isInMenu = false;
    public static boolean soundOn = true;
    public static boolean musicOn = true;
    public static boolean creatingWorld = false;
    public static boolean loadingWorld = false; 
    public static boolean savingWorld = false;

    public static int gamemode = 0;
    public Image screen;

    public static int fps;
    public int totalTime;

    public static Level level;
    public static SecondBlockLayer secondBlockLayer;
    public static Character character;
    public static Inventory inventory;
    public static WorkBench workBench;
    public static Sky sky;
    public static InGameMenu inGameMenu;
    public static Spawner spawner;
    public static Checker checker;
    public static ArrayList<Mob> mob = new ArrayList<Mob>();

    public Component() {
        setPreferredSize(size);
        //Adds key listeners
        addKeyListener(new Listening());
        addMouseListener(new Listening());
        addMouseMotionListener(new Listening());
        addMouseWheelListener(new Listening());
        addKeyListener(new InGameMenu());
    }

    public void start() {
        frame = new JFrame();

        Image cursor = null;
        Image icon = null;

        try {
            cursor = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/cursors/cursor.png"));
            icon = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/icon.png"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Making a cursor.
        Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Point cursorHotSpot = new Point(0, 0);
        Cursor customCursor = toolkit.createCustomCursor(cursor, cursorHotSpot, "default");
        frame.setCursor(customCursor);

        frame.add(this);
        frame.pack();
        realSize = new Dimension(frame.getWidth(), frame.getWidth());
        frame.setTitle(name);
        frame.setSize(size);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setIconImage(icon);

        //Defining objects, ect.
        new Tile(); //Loading images.
        level = new Level();
        secondBlockLayer = new SecondBlockLayer();
        character = new Character(Tile.tileSize, Tile.tileSize * 2);
        inventory = new Inventory();
        workBench = new WorkBench();
        sky = new Sky();
        inGameMenu = new InGameMenu();
        spawner = new Spawner();
        checker = new Checker();

        //Starting game loop.
        isRunning = true;
        new Thread(this).start();

    }

    public void stop() {
        isRunning = false;
    }

    public static JFrame frame;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Component component = new Component();

        new Menu(component);
    }

    private void clearDeadMobs() {
        for(int i = 0; i < mob.size(); i++) {
            if(mob.get(i).mobHealth <= 0) {
                mob.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public void tick() {

//      if(frame.getWidth() != realSize.width || frame.getHeight() != realSize.height) {
//          frame.pack();
//      }

        if(!isInMenu) {
        character.tick();
        level.tick((int) sX, (int) sY, (pixel.width / Tile.tileSize) + 2, (pixel.height / Tile.tileSize) + 2); 
        sky.tick();
        inventory.tick();
        checker.tick((int) sX, (int) sY, (pixel.width / Tile.tileSize) + 2, (pixel.height / Tile.tileSize) + 2);
        workBench.tick();

        for(int i = 0; i < mob.toArray().length; i++) {
            mob.get(i).tick();
            }   

        clearDeadMobs();

        }else { 

        inGameMenu.tick();  
        }   

    }

    public void render() {
        Graphics g = screen.getGraphics();

        //Drawing things
        sky.render(g);

        secondBlockLayer.render(g, (int) sX, (int) sY, (pixel.width / Tile.tileSize) + 2, (pixel.height / Tile.tileSize) + 2);
        level.render(g, (int) sX, (int) sY, (pixel.width / Tile.tileSize) + 2, (pixel.height / Tile.tileSize) + 2);
        if(!Character.isDead) {
        character.render(g);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < mob.toArray().length; i++) {
            mob.get(i).render(g);
        }
        if(!Character.isDead) {
        inventory.render(g);
        workBench.render(g);
        }

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        if(isDebug) {
        g.drawString(fps+" FPS", 5, 12);
        g.drawString("X: " + Math.round(sX) / 18, 6, 24);
        g.drawString("Y: " + Math.round(sY) / 18, 6, 35);
        g.drawString("Version: " + version, 6, 46);
        g.drawString("Width: " + getWidth(), 6, 57);
        g.drawString("Height: " + getHeight(), 6, 68);
        g.drawString("IsRaining: " + Sky.isRaining, 6, 79);
        g.drawString("Time: " + Sky.dayFrame, 6, 90);
        }

        if(isInMenu) {
            inGameMenu.render(g);
        }

        if(Character.isDead) {
            g.setColor(new Color(255, 100, 100, 150));
            g.fillRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.setFont(new Font("", Font.PLAIN, 24));
            g.drawString(deathText, 117, 135);
        }

        if(timer < 250) {
            timer++;
            movingTimer += 0.1;

            if(movingTimer > 20) {
                movingTimer = 0;
            }
            //Creating a new world
            if(creatingWorld) {
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.drawImage(Tile.menu, WIDTH - 10, HEIGHT - 10, null);
            g.drawString("Generating terrain", 125, 80);
            g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            g.fillRect(50, 100, timer, 10);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawRect(50, 100, 250, 10);
            }
            if(loadingWorld) {
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g.drawImage(Tile.menu, WIDTH - 10, HEIGHT - 10, null);
                g.drawString("Loading Terrain", 125, 80);
                g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                g.fillRect(50, 100, timer, 10);
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawRect(50, 100, 250, 10);
            }
            if(savingWorld) {
                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                g.drawImage(Tile.menu, WIDTH - 10, HEIGHT - 10, null);
                g.drawString("Saving", 125, 80);
                g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                g.fillRect(50, 100, timer, 10);
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawRect(50, 100, 250, 10);
            }
        }
        g = getGraphics();

        g.drawImage(screen, 0, 0, size.width, size.height, 0, 0, pixel.width, pixel.height, null);
        g.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        screen = createVolatileImage(pixel.width, pixel.height);

        int frames = 0;
        double nonProcessedSeconds = 0;
        long prevousTime = System.nanoTime();
        double secondsPerTick = 1 / 60.0;
        int tickCount = 0;
        boolean hasTicked = false;
        int totalTime = 0;

        this.totalTime = totalTime;

        while(isRunning) {
            long currentTime = System.nanoTime();
            long passedTime = currentTime - prevousTime;
            prevousTime = currentTime;
            nonProcessedSeconds += passedTime  / 1000000000.0;

            while(nonProcessedSeconds > secondsPerTick) {
                tick();
                nonProcessedSeconds -= secondsPerTick;
                hasTicked = true;
                tickCount++;
                    if(tickCount % 60 == 0) {
                        prevousTime += 1000;
                        fps = frames;
                        frames = 0;
                    }
            }
            if(hasTicked) {
                frames++;
            }
            frames++;
            requestFocus();
            tick();
            render();

            try{
                Thread.sleep(5);
            }catch(Exception e) { }
        }
    }
}
```

The menu Class:

```
public class Menu extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public int width = 800;
    public int height = 600;

    private JPanel window = new JPanel();
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    private Rectangle rPlay, rOptions, rHelp, rExit, rSound, rMusic, rBack, rControls, rChangeLogs, rCreateNewWorld, rLoadWorld;
    ImageIcon icon1 = null;
    ImageIcon icon2 = null;
    ImageIcon icon3 = null;
    ImageIcon icon4 = null;
    ImageIcon background = null;

    private int buttonWidth = 200;
    private int buttonHeight = 50;

    private String title = "MegaTale Alpha";

    public Menu(Component component) {

        frame.setTitle(title);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(component);
        frame.getContentPane().add(window);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);


        Image icon = null;
        try {
            icon = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/icon.png"));
             icon1 = new ImageIcon(ImageIcon.class.getResource("/button.png"));
             icon2 = new ImageIcon(ImageIcon.class.getResource("/button2.png"));
             icon3 = new ImageIcon(ImageIcon.class.getResource("/button3.png"));
             icon4 = new ImageIcon(ImageIcon.class.getResource("/button4.png"));

        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        frame.setIconImage(icon);
        window.setLayout(null);
        window.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

        drawButtons();
        //Sound.playMusic("/sounds/music1.wav");    

        frame.repaint();
    }

    private void drawButtons() {

        // MAIN MENU
        JButton play = new JButton("Play");
        rPlay = new Rectangle((width / 2) - (buttonWidth / 2), 120, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
        play.setBounds(rPlay);
        play.setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
        play.setVerticalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
        play.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        play.setIcon(icon1);
        play.setVisible(true);
        window.add(play);


        // Main Menu
        play.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Sound.playSoundEffect("/sounds/short_click.wav");
                play.setVisible(false);
                options.setVisible(false);
                help.setVisible(false);
                exit.setVisible(false);

                createNewWorld.setVisible(true);
                loadWorld.setVisible(true);
                back.setVisible(true);

///////////////////////////////

    // Play.
    createNewWorld.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Sound.playSoundEffect("/sounds/short_click.wav");
            Component component = new Component();
            Component.creatingWorld = true;
            Component.loadingWorld = false;
            frame.dispose();
            // STARTS THE GAME
            component.start();
            if(new Random().nextInt(100) < 50) {
                //Music.music2();
            } else if(new Random().nextInt(100) < 50) {
                //Music.music3();
            }

        }
    });
}
    //TODO: Render
    public void render(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("Render");
    }
}
```

Comment: Additional details are needed

Comment: You should avoid calling your classes either Component or Menu as these are both standard class in j2se

Comment: @ControlAltDel I added the classes

Comment: TL; DR; consider posting [mcve]

Comment: can someone help me please? Its been a while...